# Sharing a Core Data Database between view controllers in a UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am working on an application which uses a UITabBarViewController to hold two UITableViewControllers.

In the Story Board, I pull out the two `UITableVIewController`s which are called `firstTVC` & `secondTVC` and then embed them in a `UITabBarController`.

I have a `UIDocument` `@property` with a `fetchedResultsController` in `firstTVC` that works great, but I haven't figured out how to pass the `ManagedObjectContext` `@property` from `firstTVC` to `secondTVC`.

I have thought about doing it in the app delegate, but I have read that it is considered taboo (especially in iOS 5).

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caborca,

Apple's standard Core Data template maintains the MOC on the AppDelegate. Why do you have a problem using it? (Yes, some folks believe all singletons are "code smell.") That said, this is hanging off of a singleton defined by the Cocoa Touch framework. It already exists and is available everywhere in your code.

If that doesn't work for you and you are instantiating via nibs, then you are going to need to create a custom delegate or read the singleton and store it locally in your -viewDidLoad method.

Andrew

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that's what I'll do.

Comment: I ended up using a UIManagedDocument. Each major view controller opens the same document when it needs it. I used the procedure that the Stanford Instructyr uses in his lectures.

Comment: Caborca, I'm glad you found an answer you're happy with using. Andrew